# strip characters after finding special character

Tags: jsp

I am using jsp for a web based project. i want to remove all the characters after '@' including '@'.

suppose I got "stackoverflow@stack.com" as input from a user. I have to remove the characters after @ and also '@' i.e.

```
o/p is stackoverflow
```

I think one way is using java array OR by regex. 
Please suggest me the better way of solving this problem. Are there any other ways of solving this??

How can I do it using JSP? I can not use javascript for this only jsp.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the Java String?

One way:

```
String output = input;
int at = input.indexOf('@');
if (at != -1) {
    output = input.substring(0, at); 
}
```

(it could be optimised into less lines, but this is the clearest way to write it).

Or

```
String output = input.split("@", 2)[0];
// I prefer the first way, this is a bit more wasteful, but that is probably
// just a personal hang up from the days of embedded C ;-)
```